# Unable to get public profile url from LinkedIn in Android (BufferedInputStream is closed)

Tags: android, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am unable to get the public profile url and get or post from the LinkedIn api in Android. I'm using linkedin-j-android source. I'm able to get successful accesstoken but when calling this line from `OnNewIntent`.

Edited: I have internet permission in my app. So this will not be a problem.

```
Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL));
```

---

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     

        String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
        client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);      
        Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL));
        Log.v("","PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL:" + profile.getPublicProfileUrl());
    }
```

the app crashes. Below is the log trace.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiXppClient.unmarshallObject(LinkedInApiXppClient.java:167)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.readResponse(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3710)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3777)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3725)
at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.getProfileForCurrentUser(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:1122)
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have the internet permission in your app?

Comment: Yes, i have internet permission.

Answer (score 2):

is this code snippet working for you :

```
   Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
   Log.v("","PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL:" + profile.getPublicProfileUrl());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because it may help some people. The code was right from my end, the problem was in `intent-filter`. `android:scheme` and `android:host` mismatch with OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL. When changing this, problem solved.